# Finding the most common name in passwd file

Tags: text-processing, command-line, passwd

I have a question on getting the most common names in the `/etc/passwd` file on Unix.

Is this the correct command?:

```
cut -d: -f5 /etc/passwd | uniq -c | sort -i | sort -n
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

You want to `sort` before you `uniq`, `uniq` only looks for adjacent unique lines, so if they aren't sorted first they likely won't be affected.

You might want something like:

```
cut -d: -f5 /etc/passwd | sort -i | uniq -c | sort -nk1,1
```